# Get more than two inputs in a JavaFX Dialog

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, dialog

I trying to build the text dialog where the user enter the event name, event size, and the selected the venue.

[image]

My problem is in how can I gather the inputs; here what I did so far:

```
eventName = new TextField();
eventSize = new TextField();
ObservableList<Venue> options = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(model.getVenuesList());
VeunueList = new ComboBox<Venue>(options);
```

I create a class that encapsulate all my inputs:

```
public class MyResult {
    String eventname;
    String eventsize;
    Venue venue;
}
```

I define the variable to be object of class `Myresult`:

```
private Dialog<MyResult> dialog ;
private Optional<MyResult> EventInput;
```

The problem is how to write return statement in the result converter; it gives me error:

```
dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
        if (dialogButton == submit) {
            return new MyResult(eventName.getText(),eventSize.getText(),VeunueList.getValue())
        }
        return null;
    });

    EventInput = dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: You can get the choice with `VenueList.getValue()`. Why not write a simple class to encapsulate the three pieces of data, instead of the ugly `Pair<Pair<String, String>, String>`? (Surely you're going to want something that holds these data in a single object elsewhere in the application anyway?)

Comment: thank you for your comment , Apparently I am new to Java, I like your idea of encapsulating all data in one class , I will try do that thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear where your fragment goes awry, but getting the types correct for a call to [`setResultConverter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#setResultConverter-javafx.util.Callback-) is sometimes problematical. The example below illustrates a [`Dialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) that collects inputs from a `TextField`, `DatePicker` and `ComboBox<Venue>`. In the `ComboBox<Venue>`, the choice of `Venue` comes from an `enum`, and the corresponding `ComboBox` model is constructed using the enum's implicit [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3) method. The `resultConverter` property's `Callback` returns a new instance of `Results` having the current values of the various view components. The `Optional<Results>` shows those values `ifPresent()`. Some related examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjavafx%5D%20dialog%20setResultConverter) and in the tutorial, [*JavaFX improvements in Java SE 8u40*.](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2991463/learn-java/javafx-improvements-in-java-se-8u40.html)

[image]

Console: `Name 2017-05-24 Elsewhere`

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/44147595/230513
 * @see http://www.javaworld.com/article/2991463/
 */
public class DialogTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Dialog<Results> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog Test");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Please specify…");
        DialogPane dialogPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
        dialogPane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
        TextField textField = new TextField("Name");
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
        ObservableList<Venue> options =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(Venue.values());
        ComboBox<Venue> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        dialogPane.setContent(new VBox(8, textField, datePicker, comboBox));
        Platform.runLater(textField::requestFocus);
        dialog.setResultConverter((ButtonType button) -> {
            if (button == ButtonType.OK) {
                return new Results(textField.getText(),
                    datePicker.getValue(), comboBox.getValue());
            }
            return null;
        });
        Optional<Results> optionalResult = dialog.showAndWait();
        optionalResult.ifPresent((Results results) -> {
            System.out.println(
                results.text + " " + results.date + " " + results.venue);
        });
    }

    private static enum Venue {Here, There, Elsewhere}

    private static class Results {

        String text;
        LocalDate date;
        Venue venue;

        public Results(String name, LocalDate date, Venue venue) {
            this.text = name;
            this.date = date;
            this.venue = venue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```