# How to support macOS character input in JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, javafx, unicode

On a mac pressing and holding certain keys (such as e, i, o) will bring up selection menu like the one below. Pressing one of the numbers shown will type the character associated with it. This feature does not seem to work in any JavaFX8's TextField. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: macOS character selection]

[image]

**E.g.**

If I press and hold the e key, a *single* e will be typed regardless of how long I hold it and this menu will popup. Then if I press 2, the "e" will be replaced with an "é". In a TextField this does not happen. Instead of getting "é" i get "eeeeeee2".

Comment: What application? What Mac OS X version?

Comment: @trashgod. As far as I've been able to tell the menu shown in the gif will show up anywhere you can type something. I'm on 10.12, but I know it's also present in 10.11, before that I honestly don't remember.

Comment: Ah, you have to turn off key repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to create the input widget shown. As a workaround, open `System Preferences > Keyboard`, select `Show Keyboard, Emoji and Symbol Viewers in menu bar` and choose `Show Keyboard Viewer` from the menu bar.

[image: Keyboard Viewer]

Use the <kbd>option</kbd> key to highlight the available modifiers. For example, <kbd>option-`</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd> enters <kbd>è</kbd>. You can also choose `Show Emoji and Symbols` for other symbols. Here's the result using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172143/230513) on my keyboard/language combination:

[image]

See also [*MacOS Sierra: Enter characters with accent marks*](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25643).

Comment: Interesting workaround. I have been using the Show Emoji & Symbols, but have not had the need to use the keyboard before. As for how create the input widget it it simply holding the button on the keyboard pressed, I update the original post with a gif of it in action.