# Javafx Combox getSelectedIndex returns -1

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm new to JavaFX, I'm getting this weird exception whenever I select an item from `ComboBox`, I have a bunch of records in the database that I'm fetching and putting in the combo box as String, the thing is when I select the items in the Combobox I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`, sometimes I can display the information needed from the ComboBox and sometimes I can't, what is causing this error? and how can I fix it, help will be appreciated?

Here is the **ComboBox action** method:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> recherche;

@FXML
private void Combo(ActionEvent event) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {

            int selectedIndex = this.recherche.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println("**************selected intedx "+selectedIndex); //prints -1 and throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException

            ObservableList<String> listPayment = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(PaymentQueries.listOfPayamentDates(listOfData);
            recherche.setItems(listPayment);
            recherche.setEditable(true);
            //for autocompletion
            TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(recherche.getEditor(), recherche.getItems());

        });

    }
```

I call this method before I show the Combobox:

```
 public void reload() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {

            clearFields();
            ObservableList<String> listEnfant = FXCollections.observableArrayList(EnfantQueries.getData().getNoms());
            recherche.setItems(listEnfant);
            recherche.setEditable(true);
            TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(recherche.getEditor(), recherche.getItems());
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the initialization of the recherche items? I mean where do you call the setItems() first time? If the answer is inside the Combo method then the reason you are taking -1 for the selectedIndex is because you have no items inside. create the 
@FXML public void initialize() method and set the items to combobox

Comment: No, I'm using a menuBar so each time I click a menu item I call setItems() on my recherche comboBox, also I'm getting all the items I expect in the comboBox, so it's not about not getting the items, everything works eccept for when I actually select an Item, I'm using a reload method when I click on teh menu Item, I added it to the code

Comment: hmm with an error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException + you are saying that you can view all the items on the combobox ( at least until you select one ) I can only assume that you somehow remove the items before you can actually can take the selected one or you set the selectedItem = -1 somehow. To be sure please print the recherche.getItem().size() before you print the selectedIndex if it's 0 then you need to find what's wrong about the data insertion. If it's not there search if you are setting somewhere the selectedIndex = -1

Comment: If you can post a working example of your problem I could help you fast ;) cause I will be able to see the whole picture. Cause now for example I can't see if there is something wrong inside 'clearFields()' etc.

Comment: The selected index being -1 just means nothing is selected, which I think happens when you reset the combo box's items list. So this is probably an expected value which you should check for.

Comment: Aside: why do you have the `Platform.runLater(...)` in what appear to be event handlers?

Comment: -1 means that any elements is selected ,but i think your comboBox has not any items ,before you select an item ,move first two lines after pushing your items in comboBox.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a common [symptom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501306/javafx-combox-getselectedindex-returns-1#comment79957447_46501306) with many causes, it may help to examine it in isolation. Starting from the example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824181/230513), the variation below listens to the combo's [`SelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html) and displays the value of the current selection in a `TextField`. Note that the combo's selected index becomes [-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedIndexProperty) when the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button is used to clear the combo's model.

```
SingleSelectionModel selectionModel = comboBox.getSelectionModel();
TextField selection = new TextField(String.valueOf(selectionModel.getSelectedIndex()));
selectionModel.selectedIndexProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
    selection.setText(String.valueOf(selectionModel.getSelectedIndex()));
});
…
dialogPane.setContent(new VBox(8, textField, datePicker, comboBox, selection, …));
```

[image]

Complete example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46504588/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/44147595/230513
 * @see http://www.javaworld.com/article/2991463/
 */
public class DialogTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Dialog<Results> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog Test");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Please specify…");
        DialogPane dialogPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
        dialogPane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
        TextField textField = new TextField("Name");
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
        ObservableList<Venue> options =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(Venue.values());
        ComboBox<Venue> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);
        SingleSelectionModel selectionModel = comboBox.getSelectionModel();
        selectionModel.selectFirst();
        TextField selection = new TextField(String.valueOf(selectionModel.getSelectedIndex()));
        selectionModel.selectedIndexProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
            selection.setText(String.valueOf(selectionModel.getSelectedIndex()));
        });
        Button clear = new Button("Clear");
        clear.setOnAction((action) -> {
            options.clear();
        });
        Button restore = new Button("Restore");
        restore.setOnAction((action) -> {
            options.clear();
            options.addAll(Venue.values());
            selectionModel.selectLast();
        });
        dialogPane.setContent(new VBox(8, textField, datePicker, comboBox, selection, clear, restore));
        Platform.runLater(textField::requestFocus);
        dialog.setResultConverter((ButtonType button) -> {
            if (button == ButtonType.OK) {
                return new Results(textField.getText(),
                    datePicker.getValue(), comboBox.getValue());
            }
            return null;
        });
        Optional<Results> optionalResult = dialog.showAndWait();
        optionalResult.ifPresent((Results results) -> {
            System.out.println(
                results.text + " " + results.date + " " + results.venue);
        });
    }

    private static enum Venue {Here, There, Elsewhere}

    private static class Results {

        String text;
        LocalDate date;
        Venue venue;

        public Results(String name, LocalDate date, Venue venue) {
            this.text = name;
            this.date = date;
            this.venue = venue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever a problem happens _sometimes_, I think of incorrect synchronization.